# Regular expression to match hash URL string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url route I want to match only has url parameter

```
router.get('/:id',function(req,res,next){
}
```

Now the problem is other url like test, favicon all matches this path. I want to match only url path which is hash like and other related hash strings which will be random.

```
%242a%2410%24mbh0scotTihKwL69eKwVBuSoAShai4Qo8yY0HLPRlh0Pq0ospfAcm
```

I have tried with regular expression but , i dont seem to get my regex to match.

```
[a-z0-9][-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{50,}$
```

I want to match any string with special characters with length of 50 and above .Can anyone help me ? Thank you

Comment: I think you wanted to write `^[-a-zA-Z0-9!$%^&*()_+|~=\`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{50,}$` or `^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9!$%^&*()_+|~=\`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{49,}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to match any string with special characters with length of 50 and above

In this case, you may use the [following pattern](https://regex101.com/r/J1gzl1/1):

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{50,}$
```

However, if you need to require the first char to be an ASCII letter or digit, you can do it either by rewriting the pattern as [this one](https://regex101.com/r/J1gzl1/2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{49,}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^                                           ^^^^
```

Or by using a lookahead (so as to keep `50` as the min argument) (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/J1gzl1/3)):

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])[-a-zA-Z0-9!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{50,}$
```

In all the cases, the main point is that you need to adjust the limiting quantifier at the end / shift the character classes boundaries and make sure you use `^`, the start of string anchor if your substring is at the start of the string. If it is not, you should remove it.